# Sphinx. Why the SENTENCE special word works in SPH_MATCH_ALL match mode?

Tags: php, sphinx

I use Sphinx (sphinxapi.php) with PHP. 
I set `SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL)` and run query with '`SENTENCE`' string.

Then I get an error

```
'syntax error, unexpected TOK_SENTENCE near 'SENTENCE''. Sphinx use SENTENCE as a special word.
```

Why? As far as I understand it should work only in `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED` and `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2` modes http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.7/matching-modes.html

Comment: havent you answered your own question? SENTANCE only works in SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED mode.

Comment: @barryhunter I guess SENTENCE should work like regular word in SPH_MATCH_ALL mode and like special word in SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED mode. I think that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx only treats it as 'special', if its all uppercase, so just change it to lower

```
$q = preg_replace('/\bSENTENCE\b/','sentence',$q);
```